# Stopping a Clip in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

So I have a GUI with one button, when clicked once, it plays the song I've got, when clicked a second time, it stops the song, but I guess I don't know how to actually stop it

```
private void playButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    int i = 0;
    playMusic(Brown);
    i++;

    if (i == 1) {
    plsStop(Brown);
        i--;
    }
    //when the button is clicked, it plays song, when clicked another time, it SHOULD stop it, but like wtf it don't?
}                                          

static public void playMusic(File Sound){
    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
        clip.start();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}

static public void plsStop(File Sound){
    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
        clip.stop();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915241/how-do-i-pause-a-clip-java

Comment: I disagree with that suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You are re-opening the clip in the `plsStop()` method. Now you have ***two*** copies, and you are trying to stop the copy that is NOT currently playing.  The two methods need to refer to the same clip, which should be a member of the class, not a local variable in the methods.